# writing a byte array from as string using an unknown dll

Tags: c#, dll, file-io

i have the following code:

```
    int BufSize = 60000000;
    int BufSizeM1M = BufSize - 1000000;
    byte[] ByteBuf = new byte[BufSizeM1M];
    byte[] ByteBufVer = new byte[BufSizeM1M];
    using (WinFileIO WFIO = new WinFileIO(ByteBuf))
    {
        WFIO.OpenForWriting(path);
        Byte[] BytesInFiles = GetBytes(content);
        WFIO.WriteBlocks(BytesInFiles.Length);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
This is the original code i was working with, trying to modify it myself seems to fail, so i was thinking you guyz might have a look:

```
  int BufSize = 60000000;
  int BufSizeM1M = BufSize - 1000000;
  byte[] ByteBuf = new byte[BufSizeM1M];
  byte[] ByteBufVer = new byte[BufSizeM1M];
  int[] BytesInFiles = new int[3]
  using (WinFileIO WFIO = new WinFileIO(ByteBuf))
      WFIO.OpenForWriting(path);
      WFIO.WriteBlocks(BytesInFiles[FileLoop]);
  }
```

`FileLoop` is an `int` between 0-3 (the code was run in a loop)
this was used for testing write speed.
how would one change it to write actual content of a string?

the WFIO dll was provided to me without instructions and i cannot seem to get it to work.
the code above is the best i could get, but it writes a file filled with spaces instead of the actual string in the `content` variable. help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing a step here. Once you've done:

```
Byte[] BytesInFiles = GetBytes(content);
```

Won't you need to do something with `BytesInFiles`? Currently it seems as though you are writing chunks of `BytesInFiles`, which will have been initialized to contain all zeros when you created it.

**Edit:** Would something like this help?

```
Byte[] BytesInFiles = GetBytes(content); 

using (WinFileIO WFIO = new WinFileIO(BytesInFiles)) 
{ 
    WFIO.OpenForWriting(path);        
    WFIO.WriteBlocks(BytesInFiles.Length); 
}
```

Comment: this code is a few levels above my abilities, i am not ashamed to admit, i do not know how to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be passing only a length (number of bytes) to this components so it probably doesn't know what to write. Your `ByteBuf` array is initialized to an empty byte array and you probably write out `BytesInFiles.Length` number of `0`-s. You are putting the converted content into `BytesInFiles` but you never use that buffer for writing - you only use its length.

Comment: the dll was provided by a company, which had it built long time ago. its quite obvious what it does, and i am sure i am pretty close to the solution, im just missing something.

Comment: @Dementic sorry, I posted the first answer too quick. :)  I updated the answer - looks like you never put data into your buffer.