# read byte array from file using an unknown dll

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my next question following [writing a byte array from as string using an unknown dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847498/writing-a-byte-array-from-as-string-using-an-unknown-dll/12847610#12847610)

So I managed to write the byte array, now I want to read it back using the same dll.

I have tried the following:

```
int BufSize = 60000000;  // Size of file I/O buffers.
int BufSizeM1M = BufSize - 1000000; // The max amount of data read in at any one time.
using (WinFileIO WFIO = new WinFileIO())
{
    WFIO.OpenForReading(path);
    WFIO.ReadBlocks(BufSizeM1M);
    WFIO.Close();
    WFIO.Dispose();
}
```

this is the WinFileIO.ReadBlocks function:

```
public int ReadBlocks(int BytesToRead)
        {
            // This function reads a total of BytesToRead at a time.  There is a limit of 2gb per call.
            int BytesReadInBlock = 0, BytesRead = 0, BlockByteSize;
            byte* pBuf = (byte*)pBuffer;
            // Do until there are no more bytes to read or the buffer is full.
            do
            {
                BlockByteSize = Math.Min(BlockSize, BytesToRead - BytesRead);
                if (!ReadFile(pHandle, pBuf, BlockByteSize, &BytesReadInBlock, 0))
                {
                    Win32Exception WE = new Win32Exception();
                    ApplicationException AE = new ApplicationException("WinFileIO:ReadBytes - Error occurred reading a file. - "
                        + WE.Message);
                    throw AE;
                }
                if (BytesReadInBlock == 0)
                    break;
                BytesRead += BytesReadInBlock;
                pBuf += BytesReadInBlock;
            } while (BytesRead < BytesToRead);
            return BytesRead;
        }
```

My question is, how would one use the function to read an actual file?

Comment: Could it be because you don't provide a buffer in the constructor of WinFileIO?

Comment: if you will check my previous post, you will understand i do not have experience with this kind of thing, you might be right, but i am clueless

Comment: Is it possible the file you're trying to read doesn't contain BufSizeM1M bytes? Try reading just a few bytes to see if that works.

Comment: Vote to close. Very localized to one particular piece of private code. Consider switching to regular IO objects to get access to samples/reasonable help instead of randomly guessing arguments/call sequences.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Alternatively, OP could post source code from his unknown DLL obtained using ILSpy, and get explanation of what he doesn't understand.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - you should also explain to the OP what the problem is and he might fix it (before you decide to vote for close). I edited the question, is it more to your liking now?

Comment: Explanation: you are the only person with this problem - so it is unlikely to be useful to others as asked = [too localized](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close). If your question would be "have random assembly - need to use it" than would be totally different story. As it was standing your question feelt more about personal hacking entertainment (as it is unclear why System.IO don't work for you) than anything else. I.e. Stream.Read function seem to do almost the same thing, but have in my opinion better documentation and easier to com by some samples.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - well, your last comment was a lot more helpful then "vote to close". but, from the title you suggested, it means that i did wrong trying to figure it out on my own. also, using the regular stream.read/Binary read is 30% slower then the function compiled in the dll using win32io native write. i am also required to use this dll and not any other write method by the company that asked me to do this. trust me, i don't like it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try and answer your question at a slightly higher level of abstraction, if you are working with an "unknown" .NET assembly, one thing you can try is to decompile the assembly and work out what is going on from the source.

Decompilation is easier than it sounds. Just open the assembly (DLL) using the free tool [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). You can then view the source for the methods you are trying to use in C# (or even CIL).

Looking at the source code will let you see which parts of the .NET base class library are being used, and consult documentation for that, or even post another question here about the source code you do not understand.

Without that source, all we can do is guess at the possible API and workflow your unknown assembly supports.

In spite of my advice above, here is my guess:

- looks like you are trying to read `BufSizeM1M` bytes from a file without checking it contains that much data.

And here are a few other comments on your code:

- you are calling `WFIO.Dispose();`, but `WFIO` is created in a using statement, so that line is unnecessary (this won't be the error though).
- it is possible (and desirable) that the `WFIO.Close()` is redundant when you are also having the object disposed.

**EDIT:**

So it looks like `WinFileIO.ReadBlocks` uses the Win32 [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to read `BytesToRead` bytes into a buffer pointed at by `pBuffer`. I guess you need to find another method on `WinFileIO` that gives you access to the buffer. The trick would be to look at which other methods do something with `pBuffer`. For example, there could be a method that converts it to a `byte[]` and returns it to you like that, and that might look something like this:

```
public byte[] GetBuffer()
{
    byte[] bytes=new byte[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i]=Marshal.ReadByte(pBuffer,i);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```